# Optimize Baum-Welch algorithm in HMM using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, hidden-markov-model

I'm using baumWelch in 'HMM' package of R. I'm using it to test a discrete state of outcome case.

At first, I generate a sequence with some initial probability, a transition matrix and an emission matrix I create. Then I try to use baumWelch to recover the information. I randomize the initial points up to 1000 sets and want to compare which one would be close to the true parameters.

My problem is all the outputs from the algorithm are not far from their initial seeds. That is I could get lots of local maximums in this EM algorithm but none of them is satisfying.

In the package 'HMM', I can only see the iteration difference. But I want to have a way to compare these outcomes. Is there any way to find the optimal random seed without the knowledge of the true parameters?